# PHP Passing arguments to COM object (Data type mismatch)

Tags: php, com

As the title mentioned, I managed to create an object in php using something like this:

```
$obj = new COM('{8BCD4411-D055-4DAF-BAA6-2942DDD370E0}');
```

I can call some function the object created, such as:

```
$conn = $obj->C_GetSdkVersion();
```

And it could return(by echo) the version properly when I use the browser

However, when I tried to pass some parameter to the COM object

```
$serverPort = 30000;
$initStat = $obj->C_ServerInit($serverPort, null);
```

Originally the code is written in **C/C++**, so the function was look like this in C/C++

```
long  C_ServerInit (long lServerPort, long lUserData)
```

where

*lServerPort* is the localhost port intend to be put to listening e.g.(30000)

*lUserData* could be null in this case

The error occurs:

> exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: type mismatch '

What I did:

- use com_print_typeinfo($obj); gets:

`function C_ServerInit( /* VT_I4 [3] */ $lServerPort, /* VT_I4 [3] */ $lUserData ){ /* C_ServerSDK Init function, once invoked. */ }`

- going back and forth using typecasting
- attempted to use VARIANT class

I am new to this COM object concept, hope you guys have some ideas. Thanks